# I am trying to connection my HTML frontend to node js backend using sockets

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect my html frontend to handle the socket.on event on my frontend. My nodejs server is running on 5858 port. And I am trying to run the socketio on same port but its not connecting. my nodejs code is below

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const connectdb = require('./db/connect.js');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5858
const DATABASE_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server , {

  cors: {
    origin: false,
    withCredentials: false
  }
}).listen(server);


//connection to database
connectdb(DATABASE_URL);

//  apply to all requests
app.use(cors())
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
// app.use(express.limit('50M'));
app.use(bodyParser.json())  //Body Parser MiddleWare
app.use(express.json())



io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("new connection")
    socket.on('otpnumberevent', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        let invid = data.id
           
invoicesModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  invid,
    data,   
  {
    "fields" : {"otpverified" : 1},
   "new": true 
  }
).exec((err , doc) =>{
            console.log(doc)
            if (err) {
                let response = {
                  message: "Failed",
                  doc: err
                }
                io.emit('messageSent', response)
              }
              else {
                let response = {
                  message: "Success",
                  doc: doc
                }
                
                io.emit('getotpresponse', response)
              }
    
            });
       
    });

    
  });

app.get('/' , (req , res) => {

    res.send("Welcome to Dma backend");
});



server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

and from front end I am using the html code with .php extension so  I am using the Online socket CDN to connect with socket my frontend code is here.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-YeeA/Qxn5hYdkukScTCNNOhTrv1C2RubAGButJ1rmgQwZf/HdRaCGl+JAVkqsqaNRaYNHdheiuKKuPf9mDcqKg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

                  var socket = io('http://localhost:5858', { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] }); //socket connection code, my nodejs server is running on 5858 port
           socket.on('getotpresponse' , (data) =>{
            console.log(data);
               if(data.doc.otpverified == "Yes"){

                        swal({
                            title: "Success!",
                            text: "Otp verification Successfull",
                            icon: "success",
                            button: "Okay!",
                         }).then(function() {
                            location.reload(true);
                              });

                    }else{
                         swal({
                            title: "Failed!",
                            text: "OTP verification failed!",
                            icon: "error",
                            button: "Okay!",
                         });
                    }
           })

                })
    });
```

and whenever I try to connect from front end I get this error in my console screen.
[image]

I have tried everything. Added the CORS in the socket connection which can be seen in the above code. Still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change cors -> origin to true

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(server , {

  cors: {
    origin: true,
    withCredentials: false
  }
}).listen(server);
```

If it doesn't fix follow the following:

1. Check if the socket is connected to the same port as the nodejs server.
2. If the socket is connected to the same port as the node server, check if the CORS is enabled on the socket connection.
3. If the CORS is enabled, check if the headers are set correctly, such as origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, and Accept.
4. If the headers are set correctly, check if the socket is. The event is correctly configured on the front end.
5. If the socket. If it is correctly configured, could you please check if the invoice model.findOneAndUpdate function is correctly configured on the backend?
6. If the invoice model.findOneAndUpdate function is correctly configured, then check if the io. Emit function is configured on the backend.
7. If the io. Emit function is correctly configured, then check if the socket is. The event is correctly configured on the front end.
8. If the socket. If the event is correctly configured, could you please check if the swap function is configured on the front end?
9. Could you check the location of the swap function is correctly configured? Reload function is correctly configured on the front end.
10. If the location. Reload function is correctly configured, and then the issue should be resolved.

Comment: I tried making origin true, but it didnt worked.

Comment: the code is running perfectly fine if I run the socket on different port. Which makes no sense and create issue on live server